# Trying to understand the composition of this sentence (dialect)

Tags: slang, reading-comprehension, dialects

> うん！楽しい!
> つか　有意義やな積極的に学びたいて思うことあんねんなって

> 確かにお前とちゃうみたいやな

Upon being answered "Was it fun studying x?" the character answer this. I can gather the answer then is 確かにお前とちゃうみたいやな is not very much like you, it's unlike you.

つか　有意義やな積極的に学びたいて思うことあんねんなって

From context, I can gather it may be "I never thought of studying" but I'm stumbled on the use of the adjectives.  What is やな here? 学びたいて is たい + って?

Comment: Wasn't it 積極的**に**?

Comment: Nope, やな. I checked

Comment: But your example says 積極的な. Which is it?

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you mean 有意義. Fixed yes sorry

Comment: One more thing. Did you mean particles by "adjectives"?

Comment: No I meant 　有意義やな

Answer (score 0):

や is probably copula verb (equivalent of Eastern Japanese だ) in Kansai dialects. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kansai_dialect#Copulae) with map.

About な, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kansai_dialect#Particles) says:

> The interjectory particle (間投助詞, *kantō-joshi*) *na* or *naa* is used very often in Kansai dialect instead of *ne* or *nee* in standard Japanese. In standard Japanese, *naa* is considered rough masculine style in some context, but in Kansai dialect *naa* is used by both men and women in many familiar situations. It is not only used as interjectory particle (as emphasis for the imperative form, expression an admiration, and address to listeners, for example), and the meaning varies depending on context and voice intonation, so much so that *naa* is called the world's third most difficult word to translate. Besides *naa* and *nee*, *noo* is also used in some areas, but *noo* is usually considered too harsh a masculine particle in modern Keihanshin.